# AspNetCore.Identity - How to set LockoutEnabled = false for a new user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I use Asp.Net Core Identity Nuget package for user management. But when I create a new user, its LockoutEnabled property will be set to "TRUE". This means a new user will be locked after successful create.

I've found this [AllowedForNewUsers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.lockoutoptions.allowedfornewusers?view=aspnetcore-5.0) property but have no idea to set it to "FALSE".

How can I config to create a new user that not be locked?
Or how can I set AllowedForNewUsers to "FALSE" in my project?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As detailed in [Configure ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0#lockout):

Lockout options are set in `StartUp.ConfigureServices`.

So you could do the following:

```cs
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = false;
});
```

This code specifies that a new user cannot be locked out.

Comment: If true then new user is auto lock out? I didn't understand this concept can you tell me what purpose this flag serves?

Comment: It determines if it is *allowed* for new users, not if they are automatically locked out.

Comment: What exactly is the point of this? When it is false, then newly created users can make as many unsuccessful requests?

Comment: It would appear so. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.lockoutoptions.allowedfornewusers?view=aspnetcore-6.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_LockoutOptions_AllowedForNewUsers